# Network problem with Windows7 x64

Tags: windows-7, networking

For some months now I have had a strange problem with my development machine (Windows 7 x64).

Everything works normal for hours, but then suddenly, it appears that the network stack is blocking/hanging. Nothing works, browsers hang, pings won't work, etc. This state continues for some minutes and after that, it appears to be working again. Except one thing: All network traffic constantly produces CRC errors. This persists until I reboot the machine.

Error log of Windows doesn't show anything special.

I have already tried to deactivate all other network adapters then my physical network card (adapters from VirtualBox etc).

I have also tried to deactivate my network card and use a wireless LAN USB stick. Didn't change anything.

Any idea how i could find the problem? Or even fix it?

Comment: I would update the drive if it is not the latest. Otherwise since it works most of the time, but only occasionally does not, I would suspect the hardware may be failing or possibly a virus.

Comment: driver is the latest version. if it was a hardware failure, my network card AND my wifi stick would be broken. And the wifi stick works fine in both of my laptops. Avira AntiVir doesn't report any problems.

Comment: @Goddchen You wrote: "network card AND my wifi stick would be broken". I am not sure how you can make that statement or I do not understand something. Why do you thing your wifi working cold preclude your network card from failing (we are talking about a standard Ethernet adapter, part of the motherboard, or PCI card?, or are you saying you only use the wifi stick, and it works in multiple computers)? Those CRC errors make make me think driver or hardware failure. Try re-downloading the driver and install over the current one to make sure a file is not damaged.

Comment: ok, again: the problem exists with both, network (on mainboard) and wifi stick. so i would eliminate the possibility of a hardware failure. because if it would be, the problem would only exist with the damaged hardware and not both OR both are damaged.

Comment: i have already reinstalled/updated the drivers multiple times

Comment: I agree with @KCotreau sounds like a hardware problem, I would check out the hard drive, you would be surprised at how much 1 failing sector can do to a Windows install, check the RAM as well.  If these check out, do as @KCotreau, completely uninstall the driver and install the latest driver.  If all else fails backup and reload Windows, if after all of that, replace the NIC.

Comment: When you deactivated the NIC, did you do this in windows or in the BIOS?